# after upgrade from 6.5 to 7.2 Item.Editing.EndEdit() no longer fires event

Tags: events, upgrade

We have a solution that was upgraded from 6.5 to 7.2. After this upgrade we are having issues where `Item.Editing.EndEdit()` no longer triggers `item:saving`/`item:saved` events. Therefore changes made to the item prior to the `EndEdit()` are not saved.

`EventDisabler.IsActive` is `false` and `EndEdit()` doesn't throw any exception. Anyone have any idea to what can be happening?

```cs
public void SetFieldValue(string itemId, string fieldName, string value)
{
    Database masterDB = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
    var item = masterDB.GetItem(new ID(itemId));
    var valuefield = item.Fields[fieldName].Value;
    using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
    {
        item.Editing.BeginEdit();
        item.Fields[fieldName].Value = valuefield + value;
        item.Editing.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other issues after the update? Can you edit items normally in the Content Editor?

Comment: Are you using SecurityDisabler()?

Comment: Try to check the Item.Editing.IsEditing property after Item.Editing.EndEdit(). Ofc it should be false.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko : Normal updates trough Content editor works fine. The part not working is triggered trough a link to a site that then calls some custom code.

Comment: @PhilBurton : Yes we are

Comment: @TRNKTMS: After EndEdit() its false.

Comment: Is there anything in the log files which is related to this?

Comment: Would you be willing to sanitize and provide a code snippet of how you are editing the item? If memory recalls, I do want to say that I remember having to specifically code ".EndEdit(false)".  The first param of `EndEdit(bool silent, bool updateStatistics)` indicates whether or not the editing will remain silent and not fire events. I will have to decompile the 7.2 dll in the morning and provide a detailed answer for you tomorrow.

Comment: Also, what revision specifically of 7.2 are you on?

Comment: I also suggest to use EditContext instead of BeginEdit() and EndEdit(). Here is the explination https://divamatrix.wordpress.com/2015/03/05/editcontext-vs-item-editing-in-sitecore/

Comment: EditContext was declared obsolete in 2006. http://sitecore.alexiasoft.nl/2006/04/03/new-way-of-editing-items/

Comment: @PeteNavarra Sitecore 7.2 (rev. 160123)

Comment: @PeteNavarra I have added a codesnippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was caused by an `replacer` being `mode="on"`

```
<replacer mode="on" id="publish" type="Sitecore.Text.Replacer, Sitecore.Kernel" singleInstance="true">
```

changing this setting to `mode="off"` fixes the issue:

```
<replacer mode="off" id="publish" type="Sitecore.Text.Replacer, Sitecore.Kernel" singleInstance="true">
```

Answer (score 3):

### Response - Stop Gap Answer

I believe what is occurring is an error in the saving of the Item when updating the statistic. The reason I bring this up, is because of your information that the **item doesn't save**.  In both versions 6.5 and 7.2, the functionality inside of the EndEdit action has been relatively consistent.

Try to save the item using the following: `item.Editing.EndEdit(false,true);`

> This is a band-aid solution, to isolate where the error is occuring. If this yields additional information to formulate a solution, I'll adjust this answer as needed.

### Why I Think This

If you look in the `AcceptChanges()` method:

```cs
/// <summary>Ends an edit operation.</summary>
/// <param name="updateStatistics">if set to <c>true</c> this instance is update statistics.</param>
/// <param name="silent">if set to <c>true</c> this instance is silent.</param>
/// <returns>The changes.</returns>
/// <remarks>
///     <para>Editing an item without calling BeginEdit throws an exception.</para>
///     <para>It is usually easier and more readable to using the EditContext class instead
/// of a BeginEdit and EndEdit pair.</para>
/// </remarks>
public bool AcceptChanges(bool updateStatistics, bool silent)
{
  bool readOnlyStatistics = this.m_item.RuntimeSettings.ReadOnlyStatistics;
  try
  {
    if (!updateStatistics)
      this.m_item.RuntimeSettings.ReadOnlyStatistics = true;
    if (!silent)
      return ItemManager.SaveItem(this.m_item);
    using (new EventDisabler())
      return ItemManager.SaveItem(this.m_item);
  }
  finally
  {
    this.m_item.RuntimeSettings.ReadOnlyStatistics = readOnlyStatistics;
  }
}
```

The `try{}finally{}` is what I'm looking at. There is no catch, and no logging (at this point in the code) that something bad happened. It may not be getting far enough in the save item, which would then bomb the events.

### Follow Up Suggestions

1. Exam your Sitecore logs and make sure that there isn't an error message related to saving the item.
2. Add some logging to your `SetFieldValue()` method to see if it's a particular field and/or value.